# Add constant to few values in a vector - R

Tags: r

I have a vector with 5 elements. I need to add a constant value 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements.

```
ar = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
ar = ar[2:3]+5
```

Expected output:

```
0 5 5 5 0
```

Comment: `ar[2:4] <- ar[2:4]+5`

Comment: To clarify, `ar = ...` simply overwrites the object. You need to assign back the new values to the correct positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already know the index you can use these to do want to use them

```
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
x[2:3] <- x[2:3] + 5
x
# [1] 0 6 7 3 4 5
```

If you don't know the index, you can use logical subsetting:

```
x[x<2] <- x[x<2] + 5
x
# [1] 5 6 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
> ar = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> ar[2:4] = ar[2:4] + 5
```

output:

```
> ar
[1] 0 5 5 5 0
```

Comment: This only works if the initial values are `0`. OP said he needs to `add a constant value` to some positions of the vector, which is not what you are doing here.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Changes were added